# Display a Server Desktop To Remote User

Tags: server, ssh, xorg, desktop-environments, remote-desktop

I installed Ubuntu desktop to my AWS server, and it boots successfully. I know this because AWS lets me take an instance screenshot, and it shows the log-in screen of the desktop. The only problem is, is when I log on via PuTty- with X11 enabled, I still get the terminal. I know for a fact the desktop is there- is it that X11 doesn't support transferring those graphics to my Xserver? If so, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

X11 over SSH allows you to run a graphical program on the remote machine and have it display on the X server on the local machine.

So, for instance, you could log in with PuTTY and then type `gvim` and the graphical Vim window would appear on your local display instead of the desktop on the remote server.

It *isn't* a tool for cloning the display of a X server on the remote system to the local system. For that you'd want to use a tool like VNC.